# How to create remote branch in upstream from an existing remote branch using Sourcetree?

Tags: git, github, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I am pretty much new to git and Sourcetree. I read the doc, but I am not able understand few things. Could someone help me how to create a new remote branch from an existing remote branch using Sourcetree. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In SourceTree, you can not create a remote branch from an existing remote branch directly.

And there are two workarounds to create a remote branch from a existing remote branch in your local repo:

#### Workaround 1: create a local branch from the existing remote branch and then push the new created branch to remote

First, create a new local branch from an existing remote branch by below steps:

In the commit history graph in SourceTree GUI -> select Show Remote Branches -> right click the existing remote branch (as the example `origin/b1` in below graph) -> Checkout.

[image]

In the Checkout window -> select Checkout New Branch Tab -> name the new branch name (the name for the new remote branch you want to create, such as `newBranch`) ->  deselect Local branch should track remote branch -> OK.

[image]

Then, push the new created local branch to remote

Click Push -> select the new create branch (such as `newBranch`) -> Push.

After push the `newBranch` to remote, git will create a remote branch names `newBranch`.

#### Workaround 2: create a remote branch directly in git commandline

You can open the commandline by the Terminal button, and then execute beblow command:

```
git push origin origin/branch:refs/heads/newbranch
```

Such as if you want to create a new remote branch names `new` from the existing branch names `mybranch`, you can use the command:

```
git push origin origin/mybranch:refs/heads/new
```